# When creating a column using liquibase, how do I specify a value for that column based on an existing column?

Tags: liquibase

I have an existing mysql table with two columns a and b.

I now want to add a column c to that table.

c should be nullable, should have a default value of NULL, except in those rows where column b has the value 10. Where b has the value 10, c should have a value X.

I understand that it is fairly simple to do this using SQL, but I want to do this using liquibase, since liquibase is what we use for our schema migrations.

Comment: You will need to use a `<sql>` tag in Liquibase.

Comment: Thank you, @a_horse_with_no_name; that worked quite nicely!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new column with default value from existing column in Liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172172/how-to-add-new-column-with-default-value-from-existing-column-in-liquibase)

Answer (score 55):

Have you already tried something like this?

```
<addColumn tableName="SGW_PRODOTTI_INFO_ATTRIBUTE">
    <column name="AlternativeListPrice" type="double" defaultValue="0.0">
    <constraints nullable="true"/>
    </column>
</addColumn>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the best solution without using plain sql is following:

- Use [addColumn](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_column.html) change, as Walter wrote;
- Use [update](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html) change.

You can choose to use both changes within a changeset, but a good practice is to separate each one by a separated changeset for liquibase transaction/rollback purposes.

Answer (score 6):

If you are adding column then

```
<changeSet author="your-name" id="your-id"> 
    <addColumn tableName="person" >
        <column name="is_active" type="varchar2(1)" defaultValue="Y" />  
    </addColumn>  
</changeSet>
```

[add-column](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-column.html)

if column is already added, and then you need to set default value

```
<changeSet author="your-name" id="your-id">
    <addDefaultValue columnDataType="varchar2(1)" columnName="is_active" defaultValue="Y" tableName="person"/>  
</changeSet>
```

[add-default-value](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-default-value.html)