# How to add new column with default value from existing column in Liquibase

Tags: java, postgresql, migration, liquibase

I'm using Postgres DB and for migration I'm using Liquibase.
I have an ORDERS table with the following columns:

```
ID | DATE | NAME | CREATOR | ...
```

I need to add a new column which will hold the user who has last modified the order - this column should be not-nullable and should have default value which is the CREATOR.
For new orders I can solve the default value part of the business logic, **but** thing is I already have an existing orders and I need to set the default value when I create the new column.
Now, I know I can set a hard-coded [default value in Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_default_value.html) - but is there a way I could add the default value based on some other column of that table (for each entity).

Comment: The documentation on postgresql says for the `default clause` (on `create table` statement): *The `DEFAULT` clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free expression (subqueries and cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed)...* And I don't think that liquibase has some functionality to add this in any way...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since no one answered here I'm posting the way I handled it:

```
<changeSet id="Add MODIFY_USER_ID to ORDERS" author="Noam">
    <addColumn tableName="ORDERS">
        <column name="MODIFY_USER_ID" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints foreignKeyName="ORDERS_MODIFY_FK" referencedTableName="USERS" referencedColumnNames="ID" />
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="update the new MODIFY_USER_ID column to get the CREATOR" author="Noam">
    <sql>update ORDERS set MODIFY_USER_ID = CREATOR</sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="Add not nullable constraint on MODIFY_USER_ID column" author="Noam">
    <addNotNullConstraint tableName="ORDERS" columnName="MODIFY_USER_ID" columnDataType="BIGINT" />
</changeSet>
```

I've done this in three different change-sets as the documentation recommends

Answer (score 9):

You could use the `defaultValueComputed` attribute, which takes the name of a procedure or function. You would have to also create a changeset that creates the procedure.

That might look *something* like this:

```
<changeSet author="steve" id="createProcedureForDefaultValue">
    <createProcedure procedureName="myCoolProc">
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myCoolProc IS
    BEGIN
       -- actual logic here
    END;
    </createProcedure>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="steve" id="addDefaultValueColumn">
    <addColumn tableName="ORDERS">
        <column name="LAST_MODIFIED_BY" type="VARCHAR" defaultValueComputed="myCoolProc">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Alternatively, you could do this using the `<sql>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @SteveDonie, but what should be the WHERE clause in the procedure or the SQL?

Comment: I don't know what your where clause should be - you didn't specify the condition in your question.

Comment: What I want to accomplish here is mainly to create a new column with the default value - the default value (for existing entries in the table) should be the same value from another column. 
For example, if I already have an entry in the table like this:
ID = 333
DATE = ... 
NAME = name
CREATOR = Steve

I want the new created column to have the value 'Steve' as a default value - for new created entries - I will handle the value in the business logic

Comment: Eventually I've managed it in the following manner (all in one changeset):
1) Create a new nullable column
2) Use the <sql> tag to update the new column
3) Add non-nullable constraint on the new column

Comment: Notice that `<addColumn>` combined with adding not-null constraint is bad practice. It will fail if table contains data. See topic: [Adding a non-nullable column to existing table fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906534/5770135).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<column name="columnName" type="VARCHAR(255 BYTE)" defaultValue="def_value" value="def_value">
```